# Проблема с приведением типов

Tags: javascript

Пусть a это string и равняется "5 + 5". Тогда при вызове мне вернут "5 + 5".
Но мне нужно получить результат вычисления (то есть не "5 + 5" а 10).

```
var a = "5 + 5";

var b = new Number (5 + 5); // b будет равно 10
var b = new Number (a); // b будет равно NaN
```

Каким образом я могу получить результат арифметической операций из строки?

Comment: `var b = new Number (eval(a));`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не советовал использовать `eval()`, т.к. он не является безопасным методом. Подробнее можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450974/218976), кроме того там же приведен пример парсера математических формул.

Answer (score 0):

Выше уже писали, что `eval` ( читай `evil` ) не очень подходит из-за безопасности, и уж лучше взять какой-нить парсер формул.

Но для полноты картины, вот еще один способ

```
function calcString(str) {
  return (new Function(`return ${str}`))()
}

calcString('5+5');
```

`new Function` принимает строку, которая описывает тело. Но опять же, можно передать любую строчку, которая вызовется сразу же, что в перспективе не очень безопасно

Вообще, если у вас уж очень простые формулы, вида `a операция b`, то можно очень просто парсить

```
function calcString(str) {
  const [a, opr, b] = str.replace(/\s/g, '').split('');

  const oprs = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a,b) => a - b,
    '*': (a,b) => a * b,
    '/': (a,b) => a / b
  }

  if(!(opr in oprs)) {
    throw new Error('wrong operation');
  }

  return oprs[opr](parseFloat(a), parseFloat(b));
}

calcString('5 + 5');
```

Но тут очень много условностей, если нужно что-то сложнее, тогда лучше искать готовое решение

Answer (score 0):

вот [библиотека math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)

```
 var a = '5+5'
 math.eval('5+5') // => 10
 math.eval(a) // => 10
```

> Можно поизучать, [код на Github](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs), на предмет реализации собственной функции/парсера. Я понимаю, сложно, но это отличный пример.